# How to create view in nested fragment from parent fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, fragment, fragment-tab-host

I am using FragmentTabHost in my parent fragment to create 3 more nested fragments:

```
fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("fragA").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragA)), FragmentA.class, null);
fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("fragB").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragB)), FragmentB.class, null);
fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("fragC").setIndicator(getString(R.string.fragC)), FragmentC.class, null);
```

Then I am running AsyncTask in my parent fragment to get variables from server and in onPostExecute I want to start creating views for all 3 nested fragments. Problem is that I always get a null pointer exception, because only first fragment is created, so I can't access views in fragB and fragC.

**My question is: is it possible to start create views for all 3 fragments in AsyncTask of my parent fragment?**

Answer (score 0):

You should not access those views. Store data in your parent fragment and use interface to get those data when fragment is created.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments will be created once you are on the tab associated to that. It destroys and recreates when you come back to the tab again. You should use a simple public method in child fragment to update the UI from parent fragment. Or you can use "Observer" pattern to update the UI.

http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#observable_objects

Comment: I know how it works, but I am asking if it is possible to associate these fragments in my parent fragment before user clicks on those tabs. I am also using my own edited FragmentTabHost which just shows and hides fragment and not recreates them.